# Is it possible to disable vibration for the notifications only (Android 6.0)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-5, vibration

I would like to have vibration for calls and touch events.
Is it possible to do this in Android 6.0? (It was possible using Android 5.0.)

Phone is SM-G900F, OS: CM-13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but only on an individual application basis.

Got to the application settings and turn this option on.

[image: disable notifications.]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>